# Using livecycle-designer, how can I add radio buttons dynamically?

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I need to add radio buttons dynamically. I will be having a set of options which will be coming form a web service call and I need to convert those options into radio buttons and show it to the user. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague as it doesn't explain what you are trying to do. I am going to make a few assumptions and will try to answer your question based on these assumptions.

Assumptions:

- Your web service call is returning a bunch of values that you need to
  populate in a set of radio buttons.
- Lets assume that you are trying to set the caption property of the two radio buttons (rb1, rb2) in a radio button list(RadioButtonList)

Here is what you need to do.

1. Check the total number of values you are getting back from your web
   service call.
2. For each value, create an instance of a radio button
   in the radio button group.
3. Populate the caption property of the radio button to display your string value. `RadioButtonList.rb1.caption.value.text = "Changed Caption";`

Do let me know if you have any further questions about this.

Thanks,
Armaghan.

Comment: Hi Armaghan, Thank you for your replay. Actually, I don't know how to do the 2nd step of yours, I am able to create an instance of a radio button but I am not able to create it on the same radio button group. Can you please explain how can I do that.